# Nginx and uWSGI: Proper permissions setup for 502 Bad Gateway issue

Tags: sockets, nginx, flask, permissions, uwsgi

In uWSGI, if I change my socket location to `/tmp/api`, the website renders. However, if I change the socket address to `/srv/www/api/`, I get a 502 gateway error.

I believe this is due to a permissions issue regarding the `/srv` folder and the Nginx/uWSGI users.

In ***/var/log/nginx/error.log***:

```
*1 connect() to unix:///srv/www/api/app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: api.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///srv/www/api/app.sock:", host: "api.example.com"
```

The Flask project code is located in `/srv/www/api`. I am logged in as `username` user.

**Permissions:**

```
$ ll -ld /srv/www/api/
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data www-data 4096 Jun 28 20:52 /srv/www/api/
$ ll -ld /srv/www
drwxrwxr-x 4 username www-data 4096 Jun 27 21:41 /srv/www
$ ll -ld /srv
drwxrwxr-x 4 username username 4096 Jun 27 21:37 /srv
$ ll -ld /tmp
drwxrwxrwt 9 root root 4096 Jun 28 23:05 /tmp
```

**User groups:**

```
$ groups username
username : username sudo dev
$ groups www-data
www-data : www-data dev
$ grep 'dev' /etc/group
dev:x:1001:username,www-data
```

I have several users setup to be in the `dev` group. The goal is so that users in the group would be able to read and write to `/srv` without also being in the root group (is this a bad practice?).

***/srv/www/api/app.ini***:

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app

master = true
processes = 5

socket = /tmp/app.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true

die-on-term = true
```

***/etc/nginx/sites/sites-available/api.example.com*** (location section):

```
location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/app.sock;
}
```

Is there a way to fix my permissions setup so that:

1. The socket would be able to be created in that folder
2. Users in the dev group without sudo would also be able to read and write the `/srv` folder and subdirectories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. I ended up setting the owners for my folder to:

```
chown -R username:www-data /srv/www/api
```

I also made sure to restart the systemctl service after each change. I don't remember doing that earlier so that was very likely the reason why nothing was working even after all the changes made. I only restarted Nginx and not the service itself -- the one responsible for creating the sockets.

To restart the systemctl service:

```
sudo systemctl restart <service_name>
```